# Keycloak-js refresh token in Vue.js 2 and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak

Hi everyone I have a problem with the keycloack refresh token and the keycloack-js v16.1.1 library, inside my application I have to make a page publicly accessible, to do everything I create the keycloak instance and assign this in a Vue plugin by myself created in authorization.js file:

```
// file authorization.js

const AuthPluginKeycloak = {
    install() {
        Vue.$keycloak = keycloak;
    }
}

AuthPluginKeycloak.install = Vue => {
    Vue.$keycloak = keycloak;
    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        $keycloak:{
            get() {
                return keycloak;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I then had to move the library init from main to the login page.
However, I left the refresh token inside the main.js with a setInterval of 170000 and set the update to 150 seconds considering that the token expires in 300s:

```
// main.js

setInterval(() => {
  Vue.$keycloak.updateToken(150)
      .then( async (refreshed) => {
         if (refreshed) {
         store.commit("updateIsLoggedIn", true);
         store.commit( "updateRefreshToken", this.$keycloak.refreshToken );
         store.commit( "updateToken", Vue.$keycloak.idToken );
         console.log('Token refreshed '+ refreshed);
         http.defaults.headers.common = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ await Vue.$keycloak.idToken }` }
         } else {
          console.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
          + Math.round(Vue.$keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + Vue.$keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
                                    }
      }).catch(()=>{
          store.commit("updateIsLoggedIn", false);
          store.commit("updateOrganizationGuid", "");
          console.error('Failed to refresh token');
      });

}, 170000 );
```

everything works fine including the refresh token, until I do a reload of the page, at which point the refresh token doesn't work anymore, could you help me please? I don't know where to turn.

Thanks.